# What is the package release process at CentOS

Tags: centos, security, package-management

What's the process if a security patch is available for a package on CentOS?

I'm waiting for bind-9.9.4-74

Since 5 days, there are this commit 'import bind-9.9.4-74.el7_6.1' on https://git.centos.org/rpms/bind/commits/c7 - I can't find 'bind' as Package/RPM on cbs.centos.org

All yum repos still ship the non-updated bind version (9.9.4-73).

I guess there are some additional steps between git.centos.org and the actual release. Which one would that be exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question was answered by Johnny Hughes via mailing list:

> The steps are that the source code is released to git.centos.org .. in
>   this case, the source code was released here:
>
> https://git.centos.org/rpms/bind/commits/c7
>
> Then the source code for all the updates that happen at that time are
>   downloaded to our build system and built.  Then we do builds for
>   x86_64, i686, ppc64 , ppc64le, aarch64, armhfp for all updates.
>
> Those builds can be looked at here:
>
> [ https://buildlogs.centos.org/c7.1810.u.x86_64/ ]
>
> (and all the other arches)
>
> Then once everything builds, it gets pushed to the signing and then to
>   CI testing:
>
> https://ci.centos.org/view/CentOS-Core/job/C7-x86_64-Pretest-Updates/
>
> (and all the other arches)
>
> Then if/when it passes, it is released.